# Correct way to wait on a std::atomic<int> in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, atomic

The following code works however it has a problem:

```
#include <atomic>
#include "windows.h"

std::atomic<int> foo;

DWORD WINAPI baz(void *) { Sleep(10000); foo.store(1); return 0;}

int main()
{
    foo.store(0);
    HANDLE h = CreateThread(NULL, 0, baz, NULL, 0, NULL);

    while ( !foo.load() )
    {
        Sleep(0);
    }
    WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(h);
    return 0;
}
```

The program uses maximum CPU while it is waiting.

If I change `Sleep(0);` to `Sleep(1);` then it uses 0% CPU, however I am worried about a couple of things:

- This introduces an unnecessary delay into my program: it will waste some microseconds if the flag is set in between polls
- This might still be consuming more system resource than is necessary, in order to wake up and call `load()` every millisecond.

Is there a better way?

*Background:* I have some code that is working using Win32 Events to wake the thread up , using `WaitForMultipleObjects`, but I'm wondering if I can use `std::atomic` flags instead, with the aim of perhaps making the code simpler, faster, and/or more portable. IDK how the OS implements WaitForSingleObject and WaitForMultipleObjects, e.g. whether it is using `Sleep(1)` on those internally too or if it has some smarter technique available.

*Note:* The `atomic<int>` is lock-free; the generated assembly for the loop is:

```
    movq    __imp_Sleep(%rip), %rbx
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    jmp .L4
    .p2align 4,,10
.L5:
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    call    *%rbx
.L4:
    movl    foo(%rip), %edx
    testl   %edx, %edx
    je  .L5
```

Comment: FYI a sleep(0) will only cause a reschedule if another thread is waiting to run.  If no other thread is waiting for a slice then it returns immediately.

Comment: `Sleep(0)` is essentially a busy-wait. Even if you specify a value greater than 0, you are still polling which is the *opposite* of awaiting. An `atomic` isn't the equivalent of events. As for portable, you 'll probably have to wait for C++ 17, tasks and futures. In the meantime you could use [Boost's futures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures)

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't wait on a `std::atomic`, they're not designed for that. If you want a non-busy wait then you want a [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

A `std::condition_variable` is specifically designed to be able to wait until it is signalled without using any CPU and wake immediately.

Their usage is a little more verbose and you need to couple them with a mutex but once you're used to them they're powerful:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex lock;
int foo;

void baz()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

    {
        auto ul = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(lock);
        foo = 1;
    }
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main()
{
    foo = 0;

    auto thread = std::thread(baz);

    {
        auto ul = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(lock);
        cv.wait(ul, [](){return foo != 0;});
    }

    thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I can't use it since I am using g++ for Windows (mingw-w64), which doesn't have `std::condition_variable`. Do you know which Windows API construct this code would resolve to, for compilers which do support it?

Comment: @Matt McNabb Windows does have its own [CONDITION_VARIABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you can't use the C++ one. Another alternative is to used auto resetting [unnamed events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Just discovered [this addon for mingw](https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads) that gives `std::thread` and `std::condition_variable`

Comment: " they're not designed for that." ... C++20 added `std::atomic<T>::wait`. Latest since then atomics are designed for that. What if I cannot change the atomic to something else but still have to wait before C++20?

Comment: A little late but C++20 addition is implemented by libcxx and glibc using `futex(2)` when available and polling with backoff when not. MSVC STL uses `WaitOnAddress`. You could try rolling your own wrapper.

Answer (score 9):

Since C++20, you can use [`std::atomic<T>::wait(T old)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/wait). It works similarly to condition variables, and does not spinlock.

To use it, you call this method with the old (current) value of the atomic, and it will block until the value of the atomic changes to a different value. (Note that the ABA problem still applies -- some brief changes to other values may be missed.)

When the value changes, other threads can make this known by calling `std::atomic<T>::notify_one()` or `std::atomic<T>::notify_all()`. Thus your example would be:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include "windows.h"

std::atomic<int> foo;

DWORD WINAPI baz(void *) { Sleep(10000); foo.store(1); foo.notify_one(); return 0;}

int main()
{
    foo.store(0);
    HANDLE h = CreateThread(NULL, 0, baz, NULL, 0, NULL);

    foo.wait(0);
    WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(h);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If all you want is to signal completion, with the standard library you have two solutions - a [`condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) and a [`future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future). Since [Mike Vine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29944112/2069064) already provided a solution using the former, I'll show how to use the latter:

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void baz(std::promise<int>& pr)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    pr.set_value(1); // fulfill the prmoise
}

int main()
{
    std::promise<int> promise;
    auto future = promise.get_future();

    auto thread = std::thread(baz, std::ref(promise));
    int foo = future.get(); // blocks until promise is fulfilled
    std::cout << "Thread yielded: " << foo << std::endl;
    thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that a `condition_variable` may be notified and waited on multiple times, but a `promise` can only be fulfilled once.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, it says

> dwMilliseconds [in]
>
> The time interval for which execution is to be suspended, in milliseconds.
>
> A value of zero causes the thread to relinquish the remainder of its time slice to any other thread that is ready to run. If there are no other threads ready to run, the function returns immediately, and the thread continues execution.

Since you're seeing the program uses maximum CPU while it is waiting, it means `Sleep(0)` returns immediately, and thus it consumes your CPU time.

The problem here seems not related to `std::atomic<>` at all.